# How to write angular module for specific HTML page in angular 2 RC release version

Tags: angular

In beta version:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
    packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}}
  });
  System.import('/app/page1/environment_main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

here i can specify which module will be loaded in my HTML page by specifying *System.import('/app/page1/environment_main')*

In RC release:

```
<script>
System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

Can you please help me to set up the module path in RC release?
I want to customize the *System.import('app')* for my every HTML page. So that i can load different module in my different HTML page.